# Populate combo box with array list in Swing

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, combobox, jcombobox

I create an GUI with an combo box which I want to populate with `ArrayList`. I tried with my coding but it doesn't work.

```
private void jcbSourceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
      ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
        al.add("A");
        al.add("B");
        al.add("C");
        al.add("D");
        al.add("E");

        jcbSource.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(al.toArray()));
        jcbSource.addItem(al.toString());
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you clarify, which not working?

Comment: No problem with the code but when I run, the combobox didnt populate with the arraylist in the gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `String` type for generics, i.e. use `JComboBox<String>` `ArrayList<String>` and `DefaultComboBoxModel<String>` like in example below

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        final JComboBox<String> jcbSource = new JComboBox<String>();
        jcbSource.setSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
        add(jcbSource);

        JButton setupButton = new JButton("Setup model");
        setupButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
                al.add("A");
                al.add("B");
                al.add("C");
                al.add("D");
                al.add("E");

                String[] items = new String[al.size()];
                al.toArray(items);

                jcbSource.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(items));
            }
        });
        add(setupButton);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill try and tell you the result after I finish dinner.

Comment: Hello sir Sergey, Thanks for your guidance. its work!

Comment: What do you mean: _combo box at my gui still doesnt know the arraylist element_?

Comment: I made a mistake by putting it into cbSource method. When I took it out and put at the main method, it works. thanks sir!